# Kept in the dark during recruitment process

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, hiring-process, recruitment

I was on interview session in multinational finance-industry corporation about two weeks ago. After interview I was told I will receive feedback until mid of October, but after a few hours I received email with request to attend the next interview session (including one interview with higher management member) before end of the week.

After second interview session I was told I will received feedback probably very soon (in one-two days), but that hasn't happened. Instead I was mailed in the middle of last week and asked to deliver documents ASAP (diplomas and certificates), there was also information that other member of the team will contact me with informations about further stages of recruitment process. I had assumed that this means interviews went well and they're intend to give me an offer.

Nonetheless I wasn't contacted by the another team member and when I mailed him with question about my process status after some time I received information that they are gathering feedbacks from my interviews and will return to my when it will be possible.

What can this mean for me? Why the process was changed after my first interview? Why they can't give me any information about interviews, but asked me to deliver documents?

Comment: COuld mean anything, best to be patient

Comment: But why they wanted my documents if they don't know what's next with me

Comment: I have no idea..

Comment: You were told mid-October ... it's only 11th October. Relax. They probably send out a batch of offers once all the candidates are identified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broken recruiting process is a standard, unfortunately. Most companies are very bad for communicating properly on this topic. And every company is different in that respect, and even within a given company, there might be great differences. Said otherwise, your experience outside the company is not a predictor of what will happen inside. Which is a positive thing, in your unfortunate case.

There are two things to do at the same time, even if they do not fit well together :

1. Do what you have to do for entering this potential hiring company
2. Go on looking somewhere else

It's impossible to know form the outside if your recruiting is going well or not. So you have to assume ***both***. They want you, but it might still fail. It's not a comfortable chair to seat in, but it should not last long.